# postfix: check_client_access of smtpd_client_restrictions not working

Tags: postfix

I have two access control files. One with IPv4 addresses which works, and one with domain names that doesn't seam to work. The file named blacklist contains IPv4 addresses and the file named `domain_blacklist` is for domain names.

```
smtpd_client_restrictions = 
    permit_mynetworks,
    check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/domain_blacklist, 
    check_client_access cdb:/etc/postfix/blacklist,
    . . .
```

The reason I have two files is because the blacklist is populated semi-automatically be a program. I manage the domain blacklist manually. This is an example of the domain blacklist file. I would like to DISCARD by tlds.

```
beauty   REJECT should discard XXXX
shop     REJECT should discard XXXX
autos    REJECT should discard XXXX
```

I do see mails rejected by IPv4 addresses, but never by tld although this access control is in front of the rejection by IPv4 address.

I also tried with cdb but it doesn't work.